# set default timezone, date first day and date format medium via drush

Tags: drush, datetime

Is there is away to set :

1. **default timezone**
2. **date first day**
3. **date format medium**

via **drush** instead of doing it via drupal web interface ?

Comment: which drupal version ?

Comment: drupal 7 .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific command to set default value. You need to set those variables using drushcommands.

For Drupal 7 version you can use below commands.

1. To set default timezone you can use

drush vset date_default_timezone 'Europe/London' -y

2. To set date first day you can use

drush vset date_first_day 1 -y

I hope this helps..  :)

Comment: What about in the version 10 of drush?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of variables using `drush variable-get`.

If you want list of date specific variables then you can run `drush variable-get date`

To set a variable using drush you can use this command :

`drush variable-set <variable name> <value>`.

So for example, to set `site_mail`, you can run

```
drush variable-set site_mail youremail@example.com
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I had to accept @parth .k answer since he is the first one who posted the answer ... But thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
**1.date first day**
drush vset date_first_day 0 -y  - set first day of week as sunday 

**2.default timezone**
drush vset date_default_timezone 'Europe/London' -y

3. **date format medium**
drush vset date_format_'name' m/d/Y - H:i   - name( format name long or short or medium)
```